# adding image inside text in elementor with CSS snippet

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I want to add an image inside the text
so in the section, I add the "heading element" and edit its color to transparent then
add an image inside the "heading element" background from the advance tab and also edit
CSS snippet

```
selector .elementor-widget-container{
-webkit-background-clip:text;
background-clip: text;
}
```

but not working, the text didn't appear
I even tried using HTML&CSS code but not working, cleans up the whole section & redo but not working
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear you want the image to be essentially the font color?

Comment: YES, WANT TO FILL TEXT WITH IMAGE JUST LIKE MS-WORD

Comment: Yup my answer will get you there! you were close with your original css just had to add the background property to the element you are clipping.

Comment: What do i have to edit in my original text

Comment: You just have to add the background property to it. That should get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the background-clip property to achieve what I believe you are going for. Browser support is pretty decent. Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

EDIT: I see you tried that. You need to have a background property on the same element that you clip.

```css
p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1.4em;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  font: 900 2.2em sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text {
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<p class="text">THE IMAGE SHOULD SHOW CLIPPED BY THE TEXT</p>
```